# How to generate OCunit test description in reports?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, ocunit

I am doing automated builds on my iOS framework. I use
[OCUnit2JUnit](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit) to produce the reports. Is there any way I could add test descriptions so that I could modify the ruby file and convert to xml? It would help understand what the tests do when I run in jenkins.

Comment: What are you using for continuous integration with?  Jenkins? did you run into, warning: Skipping tests; the iPhoneSimulator platform does not currently support application-hosted tests (TEST_HOST set).